# Dynamically add extra versions constraints to pip managed dependencies

Tags: python, pip

Is there a way to provide additional constraints on transitive dependencies to pip ?

For example, if you were to pip install scikit-optimize v0.8.1, [its setup.py](https://github.com/scikit-optimize/scikit-optimize/blob/v0.8.1/setup.py#L47) would say it depends on scikit-learn>=0.20, but the actual truth is the lib is incompatible with scikit-learn>=1.0 and will crash at runtime.

Same thing if you were to install scikit-optimize v0.7, it's secretely (to pip) incompatible with scikit-learn>=0.23 but doesn't declare it.

Can I somehow enrich my pip requirements.txt file so that pip know those additional constraints ? I considered using a constraint.txt file, but I can't make this one dynamic based on scikit-optimize version. And other qualifiers directly in requirements.txt only seem to include python version and OS, not other lib versions.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible. The next best thing, as you know already, is `constraints.txt`. -- You should file bug reports so that this errors in packaging metadata are known to the maintainers of each library and they can fix them.